# How to include header and footer in Opencart twig

Tags: php, twig, opencart

I dont want to use function load view in controller and include header and footer exact in twig file this way

```
{% include 'header.html' %}
Body
{% include 'footer.html' %}
```

but i always have the same error

Fatal error: Uncaught Twig_Error_Loader: Looks like you try to load a template outside configured directories (../common/header.twig) in "default/template/information/test.twig" at line 1. in D:\xampp\htdocs\opencart3032\upload\system\library\template\Twig\Loader\Filesystem.php on line 256

what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: "Looks like you try to load a template outside configured directories". Why don't you what to use function in controller? it is the most correct way

Comment: Because i have adjust to work with twig like it is in Symfony, or like blade in Laravel. The way it is used in Opencart dos't look clear and makes me write the extra and repeated code almost in every controller